# How to resolve NPM dependency problem with shadow-cljs using react-swipeable-views?

Tags: npm, dependencies, shadow-cljs, react-swipeable-views

I have a ClojureScript project using `shadow-cljs`. In this project I am using the NPM package `@material-ui`, which works fine.

Now I would like to use [react-swipeable-views](https://react-swipeable-views.com/). Therefor I have extended my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.5.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "highlight.js": "9.15.10",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-flip-move": "3.0.3",
    "react-highlight.js": "1.0.7",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.3"
  }
```

When I try to require `["react-swipeable-views" :as sv]` I get this error from shadow-cljs:

> The required JS dependency "dom-helpers/transition/properties" is not
>   available, it was required by
>   "node_modules/react-swipeable-views/lib/SwipeableViews.js".

And in fact, there is no `transition` directory in `node_modules/dom-helpers/`. But there is `import transitionInfo from 'dom-helpers/transition/properties';` in `node_modules/react-swipeable-views/src/SwipeableViews.js`.

It looks like a dependency bug in `react-swipeable-views`, but I am a newbie to NPM.

Any suggestions what the problem is? Or how to debug?

**UPDATE**

It seams `react-swipeable-views` depends on the outdated `dom-helpers@3.4.0` while `shadow-cljs` uses the current `dom-helpers@5.1.3`. See https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views/issues/542

Is it possible to use both? Or will I have to wait until someone fixes `react-swipeable-views`?

Answer (score 0):

You correctly identified this is caused by a version conflict.

It is not possible to use both versions, you must resolve this version conflict. You can try installing the older `dom-helpers` version as the default by adding it to your `package.json` and `npm install` it. Maybe the library that was using the newer one still works with the old one?

Comment: Downgrading dom-helpers breaks something else. dom-helpers changed major version (different api). Looks like my project is broken until react-swipeable-views gets an upgrade. :-(

Comment: why not try force installing react-swipeable-views ?